# VB.Net using VBA to access Excel Pivot tables

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

I created an xlsx file with several sheets, each having at least one pivot table which is used by some kind of chart on the same sheet. All these pivot tables use the same data from another sheet called “Data”. After I got everything to work I then went and recorded some macros and then created some VBA code to update the pivot tables whenever I ran the code.  All this works beautifully and I made an xlsm file.

I decided it was time to incorporate everything to VB.Net. My code executes a stored procedure and brings back data which I successfully put into the “Data” sheet in the correct location where all the other sheets can access it. 
I then started with the first sheet with a pivot table and this is where my problems start. Below is the code from Excel that works:

```
Sub UpdatePreviousMonth(intRecordCount As Integer)

    Sheets("Prev Month").Select

    Range("A6").Select

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ptPreviousMonth").ChangePivotCache _
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "C:\Users\me\Documents\[My Charts.xlsm]Data!R1C4:R" & CStr(intRecordCount) & "C4", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ptPreviousMonth").PivotFields("Names").AutoSort xlAscending, "Names"

End Sub
```

Here is the code I have in VB.Net which does not work:

```
Private Sub UpdatePreviousMonth(intRecordCount As Integer, xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook, xlWorkSheets As Excel.Sheets, xlWorkSheetData As Excel.Worksheet)
        Try
            Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlWorkSheets("Prev Month"), Excel.Worksheet) ' This line works...

            xlWorkSheet.PivotTables("ptPreviousMonth").ChangePivotCache _
                (xlWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, SourceData:=xlWorkSheetData.Range("R1C4:R" & CStr(intRecordCount) & "C4"), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15))    

xlWorkSheet.PivotTables("ptPreviousMonth").PivotFields("Names").AutoSort(Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, "Names")

            Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
  End Sub
```

The issue starts on the entire **xlWorkSheet.PivotTables("ptPreviousMonth").ChangePivotCache** line. **xlWorkSheet.PivotTables("ptPreviousMonth").ChangePivotCache** warns that *“Late bound resolution; runtime errors could occur”.*  I get the same warning at the **xlWorkSheet.PivotTables("ptPreviousMonth").PivotFields("Names").AutoSort** line.

And **Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15** is an exception of *'xlPivotTableVersion15' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.*

As you can see I declared xlWorkSheet so I don't know why I'm getting the warning, unless it has something to do with the rest of the line that I don't recognize.

From what I have read xlPivotTableVersion15 is optional so I tried running the code without the **Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15** and got

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

which appears to mean I'm missing a parameter?

xlWorkSheetData is the "Data" sheet where the data resides.

Can anyone help? I feel I'm close but can't find the solution(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** - I should have realized this sooner, but you can not use the RC style in the `Range` function.  This is causing an invalid argument to the `xlWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create` statement.  The code below has been corrected to use a valid syntax.

---

I would really recommend that you enable Option Strict.  You are already using some strongly typed interop variables and there is no reason to not finish the job and avoid the uncertainty of late-binding.

From the documentation for [Worksheet.PivotTables Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.PivotTables):

> Returns an object that represents either a single PivotTable report (a
>   PivotTable object) or a collection of all the PivotTable reports (a
>   PivotTables object) on a worksheet.

Since this function can return multiple types, use VB's [TryCast Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/trycast-operator) to convert the returned `Object` to a `PivotTable`.

With the version issue, learn to use the Object Browser's (Keyboard: F2 or View Menu->Object Browser) search function.  It helps to find where and how such items are defined.

```
Private Sub UpdatePreviousMonth(intRecordCount As Integer, xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook, xlWorkSheets As Excel.Sheets, xlWorkSheetData As Excel.Worksheet)
    Try
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlWorkSheets("Prev Month"), Excel.Worksheet)

        Dim pt As Excel.PivotTable = TryCast(xlWorkSheet.PivotTables("ptPreviousMonth"), Excel.PivotTable)
        If pt IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim ver As Excel.XlPivotTableVersionList = Excel.XlPivotTableVersionList.xlPivotTableVersion15
            Dim sourceDataRange As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheetData.Range("A1:A1").Resize(intRecordCount)
            Dim cache As Excel.PivotCache = xlWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, SourceData:=sourceDataRange, Version:=ver)
            pt.ChangePivotCache(cache)
        End If

        pt = CType(xlWorkSheet.PivotTables("ptPreviousMonth"), Excel.PivotTable)
        If pt IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim field As Excel.PivotField = CType(pt.PivotFields("Names"), Excel.PivotField)
            field.AutoSort(Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, "Names")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Beg your pardon, but what's the point of declaring `XlPivotTableVersionList` variable?

Comment: @JohnyL, it mainly there to draw attention to what type `xlPivotTableVersion15` is defined in as the OP had an issue locating it.

Comment: Well, fair enough, but I don't think it's a good style 'cause it's bloating the code... :)

Comment: Thanks TnTinMn, but alas I still get the same error at    Dim cache As Excel.PivotCache = xlWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, SourceData:=xlWorkSheetData.Range("R1C4:R" & CStr(intRecordCount) & "C4"), Version:=ver)

Comment: @TiltingCode, I have just verified that this code pattern works.  I suggest that you verify that the arguments passed to `UpdatePreviousMonth` are correct and also breakout the `SourceData` range to verify that it is correct.  i.e.: `Dim sourceDataRange As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheetData.Range("R1C4:R" & CStr(intRecordCount) & "C4")`.

Comment: @TnTinMn, thanks for your help! I started breaking down the code and verified everything worked. At https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/activeworkbookpivotcachescreate/089692ba-711f-405a-9a35-40a6e4e12903 I found that they didn't use a Range but instead hard-coded the sheet with single quotes. I tried that and it worked, so, I'll probably create a variable with single quotes.Here is a snippet of my new code:      SourceData:="'Data'!R1C4:R" & CStr(intRecordCount) & "C4",

Comment: @TiltingCode,  I'm glad you found another solution.  The code should work using a valid `Excel.Range` object in addition to the string declaration you found.  However, I should have tried my own advice and executed that suggested range statement   I forgot that you can not use RC format in the `Range` function (I typically use the A1 format).  If you get a chance, try the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again @TnTinMn, your updated answer does work also.