# Get name of chart for current pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

I have an Excel spreadsheet with four pivot tables and each has a related chart. Using VB.Net I update the Data Source which updates the pivot tables which automatically updates their related charts. All this works great. But now I have to update the title in each chart.

What I think I need to do is access the charts by knowing the name of their related pivot table.

I tried looping through **worksheet.pivotTables** to get each PivotTable name but get an error at the For Each line:

```
For Each xlPivotTable As Excel.PivotTable In xlWorkSheetShippedSQ.PivotTables
            strCurrentPivotTable = xlPivotTable.Name

Next
```

At **xlWorkSheetShippedSQ.PivotTables** it displays

> implicit conversion from object to ienumerable

and wants me to use `CType(xlWorkSheetShippedSQ.PivotTables, IEnumerable(Of Excel.PivotTable))` but when I do this I get an InvalidCastException. xlWorkSheetShippedSQ is the current worksheet and I've successfully used it in other places.

Is there a way to access each chart to change each name? if so please share how?

Comment: Re-read my answer to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51989319/2592875). `PivotTables` is a function that returns one of two types.  Select the proper type.

Comment: @TnTinMin. I re-read your answer and found the usage and difference between CType & TryCast in the link you provided. After using TryCast it worked as it did not return an error. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TnTinMn pretty much supplied the answer in another question they answered for me. As I mentioned in my last comment using TryCast worked as it did not return an error.